# Create id column of repeated rows

Tags: r, rows, tidyverse

EDITED:

I have a very simple question. I have a dataframe (already given) with repeated rows. I want to identify each unique row and add a column with an ID number.

The original table has thousands of row, but I simplify it here. A toy df can be created in this way.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'), 
                 var2 = c('d', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'c'))
```

For each unique row, I want a numeric ID:

```
  var1 var2  ID
1    a    d   1
2    a    d   1
3    a    d   1
4    b    e   2
5    c    f   3
6    c    f   3
7    a    c   4
```

/EDITED

Comment: How do you expand your rows in the result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be helpful to see how you're approaching this since you go from 3 rows to 6 but it's unclear how that happened

Comment: The example was wrong, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution using `cumsum` + `duplicated`, i.e.,

```
df$ID <- cumsum(!duplicated(df))
```

such that

```
> df
  var1 var2 ID
1    a    d  1
2    a    d  1
3    a    d  1
4    b    e  2
5    c    f  3
6    c    f  3
7    a    c  4
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Well, the question was completely changed by OP. For the updated question we can do

```
df$ID <- match(paste0(df$var1, df$var2), unique(paste0(df$var1, df$var2)))
```

---

**Original answer**

One way would be to use `uncount` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% tidyr::uncount(ID, .remove = FALSE)

#    var1 var2 ID
#1      a    d  1
#2      b    e  2
#2.1    b    e  2
#3      c    f  3
#3.1    c    f  3
#3.2    c    f  3
```

In base R we can create a row number column in the dataframe and repeat rows based on that.

```
df$ID <- seq(nrow(df))
df[rep(df$ID, df$ID), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("d", "e", 
"f"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```